# Django - CSRF verification failed in Cloud Run

Tags: python, django, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-build

EDIT: I tried doing the tutorial again. It now **works perfectly** so I must have mistyped something in my last attempt

I am following this [tutorial from Google codelabs](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-run-django). When trying to login to the admin panel, I am getting a CSRF verification failed.

The tutorial is about deploying a fresh empty django project to Cloud Run. There's already a provided settings.py and I tried replacing it with this block to no avail:

```
# SECURITY WARNING: It's recommended that you use this when
# running in production. The URL will be known once you first deploy
# to Cloud Run. This code takes the URL and converts it to both these settings formats.
CLOUDRUN_SERVICE_URL = env("CLOUDRUN_SERVICE_URL", default=None)
if CLOUDRUN_SERVICE_URL:
    ALLOWED_HOSTS = [urlparse(CLOUDRUN_SERVICE_URL).netloc]
    CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['https://django-cloudrun-yd43yjf7ya-uc.a.run.app']
    SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
    SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO", "https")
else:
    ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]
```

I've also tried hardcoding the `CLOUDRUN_SERVICE_URL` to the url provided on deployment, https://django-cloudrun-yd43yjf7ya-uc.a.run.app but it didn't work. With and without the slash at the end.

Also did a sanity check by writing a simple hello world view to check if my changes are really getting through.

Comment: Try `CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['django-cloudrun-yd43yjf7ya-uc.a.run.app']`

Comment: Edit your question and include the HTTP request with headers and the HTTP response. Check that the request includes the correct origin header and `csr_token`. Is your code using any of the csrf decorators? Add the code that is making the request to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to follow **step 9** of the tutorial closely. Set the `CLOUDRUN_SERVICE_URL` to your generated service URL.

Retrieve the service URL:

```
CLOUDRUN_SERVICE_URL=$(gcloud run services describe django-cloudrun \
  --platform managed \
  --region $REGION  \
  --format "value(status.url)")
echo $CLOUDRUN_SERVICE_URL
```

Set this value as an environment variable on your Cloud Run service:

```
gcloud run services update django-cloudrun \
  --region $REGION \
  --update-env-vars CLOUDRUN_SERVICE_URL=$CLOUDRUN_SERVICE_URL
```